# Linux: cat /dev/video0 into a not growing buffer

Tags: linux, cat

I want to cat a /dev/video0 device output (Transport Stream is the kind of output) into a temporary ring buffer. In fact i do not want that the file/buffer is growing over the time.

So the purpose is to have a file (buffer, Fifo, whatever) to be accessed by more than one consumer (example: tail -f, mencoder, VLC, ....).

Some kind of scenario:

```
Producer:
# cat /dev/video0 > mybuffer.ts

And then multiple access by consumer
2# tail -f mybuffer.ts > extract1.ts
2# tail -f mybuffer.ts > extract2.ts
3# ffmpeg -i mybuffer.ts ...
```

Does someone have an idea how to do something like this?

Comment: How would the ring buffer know when all of the clients have connected to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a [`/dev/fanout`](http://www.linuxtoys.org/fanout/fanout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Parhaps you want to just split the stream:

```
cat /dev/video0 | tee extract1.ts extract2.ts | ffmpeg -i mybuffer.ts ...
```

tee copies the stream to files and stdout

Comment: Thanks. Was not exactly what I searched for, but a nice approach.